# Python unittest changing variable seemingly outside of scope

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have the following Tic-Tac-Toe code:

```
class TicTacToeBoard:
board = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]

def printBoard(self):
    print(self.board)

def putPiece(self, position1, position2):
    self.board[position1][position2] = 1
```

I am unit testing the code, as below:

```
def testestablishTicTacToeBoard(self):
    test = TicTacToeBoard()
    self.assertEqual(test.board, [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])

def testPutPiece(self):
    test = TicTacToeBoard()
    self.assertEqual(test.board, [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
    test.putPiece(1,1)
    self.assertEqual(test.board, [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]])
```

Before I made the second unit test, the first unit test passed with no problem.  Once I made the second unit test, the first unit test no longer passes with:

```
self.assertEqual(test.board, [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
AssertionError: Lists differ: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]] != [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

What is happening in the second unit test that is causing the first to no longer pass?

Comment: It look like it's because the `board` is shared amongst all instances (it's a class attribute/it's static).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look like it's because the board is shared amongst all instances (it's a class attribute, not an instance attribute).

You can change your class code with this and it should work:

```py
class TicTacToeBoard:

    def __init__(self): 
        # Now each instance (self) has its own board:     
        self.board = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]

    def printBoard(self):
        print(self.board)

    def putPiece(self, position1, position2):
        self.board[position1][position2] = 1
```

If you want to convince yourself about what is really happening, you can compare the two versions (instance/class attribute):

```py
class TicTacToeBoard:

    shared_board = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"Instance board: {self.board}\n"
            f"Class board (shared): {self.shared_board}" 
        )

    def putPiece(self, position1, position2):
        self.board[position1][position2] = 1
        self.shared_board[position1][position2] = 2
```

```py
>>> b1 = TicTacToeBoard()
>>> b2 = TicTacToeBoard()
>>> b1.putPiece(1, 2)
>>> print(b1)

Instance board: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
Class board (shared): [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0]]

>>> print(b2)

Instance board: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
Class board (shared): [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Notice how the second tictactoe board `b2` doesn't have the one in position `(1, 2)` but has the two at position `(1, 2)`.